I have a problem with springSecurity validation
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/administrador/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .requestMatchers("/productos/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .requestMatchers( "/css/**","/vendor/**").permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/usuario/login")
            .permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/usuario/accederUsuario")
            );

    return http.build();

}

I don't know much about this, but what I wanted is for the validation to be in user/login, where my login is located, what happens is that when I log in it no longer lets me move forward from page to page, it always keeps me on the same page.

I don't know much about this maybe you should just start with a tutorial rather than experimenting on your own? You should at least know much enough to understand the basic concepts of Spring, Spring WEB and Spring Security, otherwise you will always get stuck at the very beginning. SO is not a tutorial site, but when you have specific coding questions you can always ask: [ask] Till then I'd suggest to follow a working tutorial (YouTube, Udemy, ...) and always have the Spring documentations handy.
